# Delphi - How To Auto Highlight 1st entryIn A DBLookupListBox On Form Creation

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

How do I auto highlight the 1st entry in a DBLookupListBox without the end user highlighting it.

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.ActiveControl := DBLookupListBox1;
end;
```

But this doesn't work, I've also tried DBLookupListBox1.setfocus on form create, but this gives an error, because the DBLookupListBox is not created yet.

Thanks

-Brad

Comment: Have you tried SetFocus in the OnActivate event?

Comment: What do you mean by "higlight"? Do you mean setting focus? Or do you mean selecting the first entry in the lookupbox?

Comment: I tried DBLookupListBox1.SetFocus; onActivate, it shows the "box" around the 1st item, but it's not highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but I would assume that you should use SetFocus in the form's OnShow event to activate the control.

```
procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DBLookupListBox1.SetFocus;
end;
```

Setting a default value is a bit more complicated because the DBLookupListBox is DB-aware.
One approach is to set the default values in the DataSets OnNewRecord event or AfterInsert event:

```
procedure TMyDataModule.cdsMyClientDataSetNewRecord(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  cdsMyClientDataSetMYPERSISTENTFIELDNAME.Value := 0;
end;
```

If you still would like to do this from the Form:

```
procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
const
  DEFAULT = 0;
var
  S: String;
begin
  S := DBLookupListBox1.DataField;

  if DBLookupListBox1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName(S).IsNull then
  begin 
    DBLookupListBox1.DataSource.DataSet.Edit;
    DBLookupListBox1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName(S).Value := DEFAULT;
    DBLookupListBox1.DataSource.DataSet.Post;
  end;
end;
```

IMHO:
Setting default values should be considered as business logic and therefore belongs in the DataModule.

Setting the appropriate focus is GUI-logic and should be done in the form.

Comment: I don't need to set the default values, just make sure it's highlighted.

Comment: Why would you want the DB-aware component to show a value that doesn't actually exist in the DB?  Because this is what the highlighting is all about - representing the DB-value.

When the user inserts a record, the DB-aware component should show the actual value for this field.  Not something else.

If the dataset is empty, then there is no value to show in the DB-aware component...

Comment: The data exists in the database.  I just want it to show the 1st item selected and highlighted, so that you know that item is the one in question.  It auto selects the 1st item but it does not show it highlighted.

Comment: Sorry, I can't manage to reproduce this situation. In my case the proper item is selected and highlighted.  :-(

Comment: it's selected in my case also, but not highlighted...  :(

Comment: One last question: Are you sure that the LookupValue and DataField items match?  The selected but not highlighted state occurs when the DataField value isn't found in the lookup-table.  We haven't delved into the details here, but if the LookupValue is a string field, for instanse, it is important that both values match in case and space.  If the DataField is defined with Size=3 and FixedChar=True.  Then the lookup table must have 'A  ' (as in #65+#32+#32) as the LookupValue, not 'A' or 'a  '.